# If I do "long-polling" with AJAX requests...what does that mean about my threads?

Tags: python, ajax, apache, http

Does each client take up one thread?  I mean...it's long-polling that one thread, right?

So , in order to support 10,000 simultaneous clients, I'll need to spawn up a server that has 10,000 threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your server dedicates a thread to each request and doesn't time out those requests, the answer is yes.  If you plan to do long-polling, you might want to consider an event-based web server.  You can find benchmarks of several python ones here:  http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers

See also: [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets)